# I need viewHolder explanations

Tags: android, custom-lists

Sorry for this post but I search on Google but i didn't find anything who explains step by step the process to create a custom checked list with viewHolder method. Someone have the patience to do it ?

Thank you so much :) :)

Answer (score 2):

> The ViewHolder class is used in conjunction with an ArrayAdapter, to
>   cache the results of all findViewById calls. This speeds up our lists
>   by up to 30 percent when we start dealing with very large lists.

Check [`this`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLNoMEmcwVM) Video that explains `ViewHolder` Class.